# How to add Wiris or Mathjax to Quill editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjax, quill, wiris

How can i add Wiris or Mathjax to Quill editor? And use it? 
Or how to convert Formula options in Quill editor to Wiris (Mathjax)?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can insert a MathJax equation by creating a new Quill module. It is detailed on this page:

https://lucidar.me/en/rich-content-editor/mathjax-and-quill-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Don't have WYSIWYG math input working, but you can see how MathJax with Latex entry can work well with Quilljs in an extension to the Jupyter notebook we are working on. See the opening post to this [Jupyter discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/BSk_4yID0KM) and the link to a brief [screencast](https://groups.google.com/group/jupyter/attach/873659b70056e/Quill%20in%20jupyter.mp4?part=0.1&authuser=0&view=1) of it working. For now you will have to look at the repositories or install to develop:

https://github.com/ColinGutow/notebook (the working branch is 'withQuill').
https://github.com/ColinGutow/nbformat

I have no idea if this will help you, but it shows it is possible.

Regards

Comment: I don't want MathJax to work with a latex entry. I want to use MathJax directly in Quill Editor. Do you have a solution?
for example: https://docs.google.com -> add-ons Options -> mathtype -> insert math equition

Comment: mathtype exists in ckeditor. http://www.wiris.com/plugins/demo/ckeditor4/php/ ......You can guide us.

Comment: I think we need to understand more about your use case. My answer was only meant to indicate that it is possible to use MathJax with the Quilljs editor. Because of the way Jupyter notebooks work we intentionally wanted the latex to show up in the edit window and only be translated to gui math when the cell was rendered. Our thought is eventually to have a WYSIWYG pop-up math editor to help people learn the latex input. It would just insert the generated latex at the cursor.

Comment: I want people to write their math questions easily without having to learn the latex formula.  I want at QuillEditor to put option mathtype popup (wiris). Is it possible in QuillEditor?

Comment: As wiris is a commercial product, I suggest the question be directed at their support team <info@wiris.com>. I suspect that if they have not integrated it with Quilljs they would be willing to do it for a fee.